# combine two makefile into one makefile got an error

Tags: c#, web-services, makefile, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to combine two makefiles (one of `rohc sniffer` and another `ulfius lib`) but I got the error: my test does not link to include file :

sniffer.c:81:10: fatal error :`u_example.h` : no such file or directory

```
#include <u_example.h>
```

I think the problem is in makefile cflags??:

```
CFLAGS+=-c -wall -I$(ILFIUS_INCLUDE) -I$(EXAMPLE_INCLUDE) -D_REENTRANT $(ADDITIONALFLAGS) $ (CPPFLAGS)
CFLAGS = -g -02
```

any one has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your cflags: `ILFIUS_INCLUDE` should be `ULFIUS_INCLUDE`, but I'm not sure that's your problem.

I don't know if that's the Makefile you use, but might want to combine `ulfius/src/Makefile` in your Makefile. The other Makefiles are for different purposes:

- `ulfius/Makefile`: Meta builder to help packager
- `ulfius/example_programs/Makefile`: Build exmaple programs
- `ulfius/tools/uwsc/Makefile`: Build uwsc (a command-line websocket client tool)